# TCP, гарантия доставки пакетов

Tags: java, сокет, tcp

Работаю с TCP и столкнулся с вопросом, который по факту упирается в понимание протокола.

Я беру некоторые данные и отправляю их клиенту, например через блокирующий сокет `clientSocket.write(data)` или через Netty `client.channel.writeAndFlush(data)`.

Вопрос 1. Предположим метод `write` завершился без ошибок. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это означает, что клиент 100% получил данные, потому что клиент выслал подтверждение приема?

Вопрос 2. Если `write` свалился по таймауту с исключением, означит ли это что клиент 100% отбросит данные? (не может ли произойти такого, что клиент выслал подтверждение что данные успешно приняты и начнет их обработку, но сервер каким либо образом его не получил? Например ack был выслан уже после происхождения тайм-аута на сервере или даже сеть отвалилась и ack вовсе не пришел серверу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет и нет.

Метод write завершается без ошибок когда данные были успешно скопированы во внутренний буфер драйвера TCP.